# Generic id-referenced json parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

In a project I'm working on I'm calling an rest-api that returns json as follows:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":0,
      "username":"someone0",
      "areas":[  

      ],
      "role":{  
         "id":2,
         "name":"somerole2",
         "users":null
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":1,
      "username":"someone1",
      "areas":[  

      ],
      "role":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"somerole1",
         "users":null
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "username":"someone3",
      "areas":[  

      ],
      "role":1
   }
]
```

As you can see user 'someone1' and 'someone3' both carry the same role object, but the second time it's referenced (at someone3) it is only referenced by it's id.

Because every response from this api is formatted this way, I'm looking for a generic way to fix this (replace the id-reference with the full object) in pure javascript.

Any common solutions to the seemingly common issue?

PS: I'm sorry for the title, I don't know the right term (suggestions are welcome).

Comment: Loop through the array, and collect all the object roles into another object that uses the role ID as the key. Then go through the array and replace all the numeric roles with references to those objects.

Comment: I would separate the roles from the users and make *all* roles "referenced" by ID. That ensures more consistent JSON data output and clearly separates the two components. Then it's simply a matter of iterating over the users and assigning the relevant JS property after doing a lookup on the now-external-from-users roles.

Comment: Please clarify "replace"; you're using these responses rather than "fixing" them and sending the fixed version back? If so, I would worry more about understanding the data than "fixing" it. *i.e.* where encountering a role with `typeof === "number"`, you'll want to lookup what that role's details are from previously read data ( which may not exist?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply map a function that makes these corrections to the initial value. Something like this should work if I understand what you are going for:

```
response = response.map( function(x){
    if( (typeof x.role) == "number"  )
        x.role = { id : x.role };
    return x;
});
```

This however will not give you the names and users field. If this is important, I recommend we iterate through the data once and make a list of roles, then go back and fill in the gaps. This would look like:

```
roles = {};

response.forEach( function(x){ 
    if( (typeof x.role) != "number" )
        roles[x.role.id] = x.role;
});

response = response.map( function(x){
    if( (typeof x.role) == "number"  )
        x.role = roles[x.role];
    return x;
});
```

The output of running that on your data is:

```
[ 
  { id: 0,
    username: 'someone0',
    areas: [],
    role: { id: 2, name: 'somerole2', users: null } 
  },
  { id: 1,
    username: 'someone1',
    areas: [],
    role: { id: 1, name: 'somerole1', users: null } 
  },
  { id: 3,
    username: 'someone3',
    areas: [],
    role: { id: 1, name: 'somerole1', users: null } 
  } 
]
```

Comment: Makes sense, I'm working on an update that will do that.

Comment: @RobG updated. I think that should fit their needs now.

Comment: @rp.beltran thanks this is indeed the result I'm after. The map method is new to me.. (and so is js)

Comment: Thanks for accepting it. The map method applies a function to each item in a collection and returns the result. You could also just use foreach, a generic for loop, or whatever you want to solve this. Technically iterating through and updating it would be slightly more efficient. Best of luck learning!

Comment: I think you can do it in one loop (e.g. all within the *forEach*) as the role shouldn't reference an ID that's at a larger index (from a common sense perspective), but that's up to the OP.